# adding user input of alphabets, not in sequence order

Tags: python, list

The program reads a product code, consisting from letter A to L. The user input have to be at least 3 characters long and may be unsorted. I've done the code as shown below. However, the code only accepts the alphabets when its in sequence, eg. abcd..if I input badc, it will become invalid. How do I fix this?
Also i can't seem to break from the while loop.

```
def addProductCode():
    while True:
        partIds = 'ABCDEFGHIJKL'
        productCode = []
        pcode = input("Enter new product code: ").upper()
        if len(pcode) < 3:
            print("The product code is invalid")
        elif pcode not in partIds:
            print("The product code is invalid")
        elif pcode in productCode:
            print("The product code already exists")
        elif pcode == 0:
            break
        else:
            pcode = sorted(pcode)
            productCode.append(pcode)
            print("The product code has been added successfully")
addProductCode()
```

Desired output:

Enter new product code: zadg

The product code is invalid

Enter new product code: badc

The product code has been added successfully

Enter new product code: abdc

The product code already exists

Answer (score 1):

`pcode in partIds` checks whether `pcode` is a *substring* of `partIds`, which for example `'BACD'` isn't (because the order of characters in a string matters).

If you want to check whether *every character* in `pcode` is contained in `partIds`, either use `all` and a generator expression:

```
all(c in partIds for c in pcode)
```

or use sets:

```
set(pcode).issubset(partIds)
```

---

(Note that for simplicity I have omitted the logical negation – since you are actually using `pcode not in partIds` you will have to add `not` in front of either of the two expressions you decide to use.)